# SSRS Matrix showing incorrect data, duplicating information from another column

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a report in SSRS, and have an issue whereby some, but not all, cells are showing incorrect data, duplicating from the cell on the left.

The aim of the report is to display an overview of a school's timetable, with columns grouped by Day and LessonCode, and rows by intSetNumber.

The screenshots below show the matrix, and data from the same dataset presented as a table (but just filtered to certain values of inSetNumber to illustrate the point).

There are various examples of the problem within these shots, but one specific case is for set 6 on L3. As the table shows, they should have 7X-Hi6 with BBU for L2, then 7X-En6 with LBN for L3; however, the matrix ignores this and shows 7X-Hi6 for both lessons.

[Timetable overview grid]

[image]

[Table of data]

[image]

The same issue has occurred for groups 9, 11 and 14, and also for other groups at other times.

I have been making reports using SSRS for a number of years, and am absolutely confident that the data set is returning the correct information, as checked in the table; I have also checked and re-checked the column grouping for the matrix, and cannot find any issue. Can anyone suggest why this might be happening, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your table design and can you supply the sample data as text so we can reproduce without having to type it all out, make sure it includes rows that are not causing a problem either as that might help investigation. If you can also share the rdl that might help but at least the data and design. Please include all the expression used in each textbox in the matrix.

Comment: I meant report design, not table design!